# Declaring dynamic columns in DynamicReport

Tags: java, dynamic-columns, dynamic-reports

I'm currently working on building reports using DynamicReports for my project.

I had a lot of problems doing this since it is my first time using such feature in java.

What I am trying to do is to create Columns dynamically. I have already solved the part of DynamicDataSource but now I'm stuck on columns.

here is my code:

```
public void raports(){
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        int mColumns = model.getColumnCount();
        int mRows = model.getRowCount();
        String[] arrColumns = new String[mColumns];

        for(int i=0; i<mColumns; i++){
            arrColumns[i] = model.getColumnName(i);
        }

        DRDataSource dataSource = new DRDataSource(arrColumns);

        for (int i = 0; i < mRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<mColumns; j++){
                dataSource.add(model.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
            }
        }

        JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();//a new report
        StyleBuilder boldStyle = stl.style().bold();  
        StyleBuilder titleStyle = stl.style(boldCenteredStyle)
                .setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE)
                .setFontSize(15);

        StyleBuilder boldCenteredStyle = stl.style(boldStyle)
                .setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        StyleBuilder columnTitleStyle  = stl.style(boldCenteredStyle)
                .setBorder(stl.pen1Point())
                .setBackgroundColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        report
                .setColumnTitleStyle(columnTitleStyle)
                .highlightDetailEvenRows()  

                .columns(
//                        Columns.column("Patient ID", "Patient_ID", DataTypes.stringType()).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT),
//                        Columns.column("First Name", "First_Name", DataTypes.stringType()),
//                        Columns.column("Middle Name", "Middle_Name", DataTypes.stringType()),
//                        Columns.column("Last Name", "Last_Name", DataTypes.stringType()).setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT)
                )


                .title(
                    cmp.horizontalList()
                    .add( //cut the code here since this is the only part needed.
```

Referrences:
[Dynamic Reports Documentation](http://apidocs.dynamicreports.org/allclasses-noframe.html)

[Might have the right codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323565/how-to-generate-dynamic-columns-in-dynamicreports-via-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could interrupt the call chains for report and use the following method in a for loop:

```
report.addColumn(Columns.column("Here will be the name", "Here is the corresponding arrColumns name", DynamicReports.type.integerType()/* here is the column type*/));
```

I hope it helps.